# Trying to change the font color of font awesome used in the navigation of Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, sass, zurb-foundation, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl carousel 2 and updated the prev and next buttons with icons from font awesome. I got everything to work, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the colors of the icons on roll over.

css

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span, .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span{
    background-color: $green;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
        font-family: 'fontAwesome';
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:before{
    // fa-chevron-left
    content: "\f177";
    color: #D6D6D6;
    font-size: rem-calc(18);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:before:hover{
    // fa-chevron-left
    color: $white !important;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next:after{
    //fa-chevron-right
    content: "\f178";
    color: #D6D6D6;
    font-size: rem-calc(18);
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*=owl-]{
    background-color: $white;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    padding: 5px 10px
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*=owl-]:hover{
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
}
```

js

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop:true,
   margin:10,
   nav:true,
   items: 1,
   navText : ["",""],
   rewindNav : true
});
```

Comment: Is `rem-calc(18);` a preprocessor function? Add the SASS tag to your question, it may be relevant.

Comment: yeah, it's part of the sass foundation system, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I never used Foundation, but if it's like Bootstrap, then you are having CSS specificity problems. Try doubling class selectors. ex.`.owl-nav.owl-nav`. If that doesn't work you can try `!important`, but use it sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include **font-family: "FontAwesome"** in the **:before** and **:after** CSS entries, along with the **content:** Unicode

```
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    // fa-chevron-left
    content: "\f177";
    color: #D6D6D6;
    font-size: rem-calc(18);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next:after{
    font-family: "FontAwesome";        
    //fa-chevron-right
    content: "\f178";
    color: #D6D6D6;
    font-size: rem-calc(18);
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Do you have the font loaded?